# bash: injecting variable into string adds extra \r

Tags: bash, curl

I have a script that uses curl to send a file to our third party cloud file storage.

I am using grep to pull out a URL provided to me in an http response

looks like this

```
curl -X PUT -T media/file.tar.gz -D - \
     -H "ETag: ${md5}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-gzip" \
     -H "${AuthToken}" \
     -H "X-Object-Meta-Date: ${today}" \
     "${StorageUrl}/dp/file1.tar.gz"
```

and then I get a bad request on the url
which prints out like

```
'PUT /v1/MossoCloudFS100213=123-123-1233a-ss9\r/dp/file1.tar.gz'
```

see that \r that just annoyingly has been injected between my variable and the /dp/?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you don't have an extraneous \r in ${StorageUrl} itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you got the `$StorageUrl` value from a web request and the web response line ended with CRLF (the web standards generally require CRLF line endings).  The shell removed the LF (newline) for you, but not the CR (`\r`, carriage return).  You'll probably need to take care of that yourself before using the URL.