# Bash - curl script, run with options

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a script after curling it, but with an option -- I get the error: `/usr/bin/install: /usr/bin/install: cannot execute binary fil`

```
curl https://raw.github.com/gist/2513225/a39232a94b25741ddb25e15755bddd5d71999b85/give-tourettes.sh | sh install
```

What syntax is wrong?  Just some Friday shenanigans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, what `curl` sends to its standard output isn't acceptable to `sh`.  If I had to guess, the first line of the file is `#!/bin/bash\r` where the `\r` is a carriage return (CR), and the system can't find a file with the CR in the name.  (And the error report is confusing because the CR spoils the display.)

Maybe you should pipe the output through `tr -d '\015'` before submitting it to the shell.

```
URL=https://raw.github.com/gist/2513225/a39232a94b25741ddb25e15755bddd5d71999b85/give-tourettes.sh
curl "$URL" |
tr -d '\015' |
sh install
```

See: [bash: injecting variable into string adds extra \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354351/bash-injecting-variable-into-string-adds-extra-r/10354650#10354650) for a related issue.

*Against this hypothesis*: `sh install` tries to run the file `install` in the current directory as a shell script.  That may not work.  Did you mean to pipe it to just `sh` to execute the `tourettes.sh`?  Or are you expecting `install` to read its standard input (and if so, why)?

The 'lose the carriage return' advice is partially relevant; you don't want CR in the data, but it may not be the only, or even the main, issue here.

Comment: The script is self-containted -- ./give-tourettes.sh is what the cronjob runs, ./give-tourettes.sh install installs the cronjob.

Comment: Me thinks I should just reverse it :) Make cron execute with a param.

Comment: You would need to save the file to disk (and might need to deal with CRLF line endings).  Then you could run `sh give-tourettes.sh install` to install it.  As it stands, though, `sh install` will try to run something called `install` in the current directory, with (in effect) `give-tourettes.sh` as standard input (and not as a file).  Were it me, I'd want the file on disk anyway.